# Using both integer and UUID primary keys in related PostgreSQL tables

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js, keystonejs

I am using Keystone.js to manage a PostgreSQL database. My database has two separate tables (`Customer` and `Order`) with a defined relationship, as outlined [here](https://www.keystonejs.com/keystonejs/fields/src/types/relationship/#relationship):

Customer:

```
fields: {
  ordersPlaced: {
    type: Relationship, ref: 'Order.customer', many: true
  }
  // And some other fields
},
```

Order:

```
fields: {
  customer: {
    type: Relationship, ref: 'Customer.ordersPlaced', many: false
  }
  // And some other fields
},
```

Everything works as expected if both tables use auto-incrementing integers **OR** UUIDs as their primary keys.

However, if I use an integer ID for one table and UUID for the other (which is my preferred approach), I get the following error in the Keystone admin UI:

```
select "t0".* from "public"."Order" as "t0" left outer join "public"."Order" as "t1" on "t0"."ordersPlaced" = "t1"."id" where true and "t0"."ordersPlaced" = $1 - operator does not exist: uuid = integer
```

Is this a limitation of my setup, I.e. must related tables use the same `type` as their primary key? Or is it possible to use UUIDs with `Customer` and the default integer IDs for `Order`?

In either case, I'm not sure whether  Keystone.js, PostgreSQL or the knex.js is the source of the error, which is making debugging difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No primary keys of joined tables do not have the same because you typically DO NOT JOIN primary key to primary key. You join an attribute column in the child table (usually defined as a Foreign Key) to the PK of the parent. **Those are the columns that must be of the same type**. Your are looking for definitions something like:

```
create table customers( id integer generated always as identity
                      , ...
                      , constraint customers_pk
                                   primary key (id)
                      ); 
Create table orders ( id uuid default generate_random_uuid
                    , cust_id integer not null
                    , ...
                    , constraint orders_pk 
                                 primary key (id)
                    , constraint orders2cust_fk
                                 foreign key (cust_id)
                                 references customers(id)
                    ); 

then to join
select ...
  from customers  c 
  join orders o on o.cust_id - c.id 
  ,,, ;
```

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you. As per my question keystone is handling the database schema etc, so I think I'll have to look into the approach this takes to joining. Based on this https://www.keystonejs.com/guides/relationship-migration#postgresql-1, and a look at my tables, it looks like they might (atypically) be joining on primary keys, which would mean these would both need to be int OR UUID

Comment: Well typically all PKs would be of the same data type or at least the same class (so perhaps int4 others int8 - due to table volume) to maintain consistency; in your case all integer or all UUID. But lets look a step forward, regardless of data type. If you join on the PK then customer id  and order id would be the same. The result being a customer could never have more that 1 order. For 2 or more orders per customer you must join FK to PK (typical).  If your table layout does not permit that **your table layout must change!** Sorry if I was not clear on that.

Comment: Again, thanks. As mentioned, Keystone is handling the database schema so I'm unable to implement your suggestions directly.

Comment: I've decided to use UUID for PK on all tables and have added a separate auto-increment column on tables where an integer ID is a requirement, which has fixed the error. I was hoping to use one or the other on a given table, but based on your answer this isn't possible, and it is undesirable to have different PK types